# Multiple table views in a single storyboard swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

Im trying to have 2 tableview in a single view controller with one tableview being static while
the other dynamic.

My view controller is set up like so
[image]

The top half being the static tableview.

i created ibOutlets for both tableViews but i can't seem to be able to customise the tables.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    //tableview2 is the dynamic tableView.
    if (tableView == self.tableView2){
        print("Tableview2")

    }
    else{
        println("HELLLO")
    }




    return cell
}
```

i get the error  *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:6116
2014-10-23 22:31:52.246 Recipe app[2857:504809] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell2 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'.

Answer (score 1):

As error says you "must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard".

Do this on viewDidLoad or awakeFromNib.

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier:"cell2")
```

Or you have to make prototype cells in storyboard and give it "cell2" identifier

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have given the prototype cells for your dynamic table the reuseIdentifier "cell2", move this line:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

into either the `if ...` clause, or the `else ...` clause (whichever deals with the dynamic table).  If tableView is the static table, it throws the error.